# installing 64bit windows guest on 64bit windows host - VirtualBox vs Hyper-V

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, hyper-v, vt-x

I have installed Windows Server 2008R2 and now trying to install multiple Windows Server 2008R2 as guest. My CPU is `Intel Core 2 Quad Q8400 @ 2.66GHz` on `Asus P5P41T-LE` mainboard. First I have to tell there is no place in BIOS to enable Intel VT-x. Intel [web site](http://ark.intel.com/products/38512/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q8400-4M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB) says this CPU supports VT-x. When installing guests, VirtualBox says:

```
attempting to load a 64-bit application however this cpu is not compatible with 64-bit mode
```

But Hyper-V can load 64 bit guest with no problem. I have tested my CPU with [Securable](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm) tool. It says my CPU does not support VT-x. The question is WTF is happening? Are there two editions of Q8400 with/without VT-x?

Comment: The 8400 should have VT-x but it is missing VT-d. So it should be working perfectly fine. Have you stopped Hyper-V and it's related services before starting VirtualBox? Running multiple VM softwares at once can cause bad things to happen (usually instability of the host)

Comment: Yes I have checked VirtualBox before starting Hyper-V services.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with Virtual Box does VMWare have this problem?  This will require running the Hyper-V Services.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem with Hyper-V being able to host 64bit systems, while on the same machine VirtualBox wasn't. The issue is that the Hyper-V service occupies VT-X right after startup, hence no other service (like VirtualBox) can claim it.

<strike>The only way I found to resolve the issue was by completely removing the entire Hyper-V feature through the windows feature settings an rebooting. After that VirtualBox was able to host 64bit systems.</strike>

See [see this answer](https://superuser.com/a/642027/326205) on how to turn Hyper-V on and off, without having to remove the feature completely.