# I get an IPv6 address from my ISP but can't use any IPv6 services

Tags: networking, ipv6

When I enable DHCPv6 with Prefix Delegation on my router, it gets an IPv6 address from my ISP (TWC) [in this block](http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET6-2604-2000-1/pft), and my PC will get one automatically as well.

When I try an [IPv6 test site](http://ipv6test.google.com/) it fails to detect anything but IPv4, and trying `ping -6 google.com` fails with `Destination host unreachable.`

Should it also provide DNS servers with IPv6 addresses?

It doesn't, but I've tried using the Google DNS IPv6 addresses on my router and on my Windows machine's settings, however that has no effect.

What else can I try to get IPv6 working?

[image: IPConfig]

Comment: It might be 'internet security' software. I have seen broken IPv6 connectivity because of broken security software. Can you try from a different machine or a smartphone/tablet/etc?

Comment: First thing I would do would be to [disable Hyper-V](http://superuser.com/q/540055/144961). If you suddenly get connectivity, then you have a configuration problem with Hyper-V.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for the tip. Afraid it didn't help though. I wasn't even able to use a webservice to ping the router's IPv6 address, so I think I'll just wait for the ISP to officially announce support.

Comment: Could also be a broken router. Beyond that, I don't think there's anything you can do except to yell at TWC for breaking the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a traceroute to your IPv6 address, (which you didn't quite obscure well enough in your image) it dies some distance away from you.

```
 1  NOPE (NOPE)  0.570 ms  0.615 ms  0.715 ms
 2  NOPE (NOPE)  28.731 ms  28.899 ms  29.085 ms
 3  sixxs-asbnva-gw.customer.occaid.net (2001:4830:e6:7::2)  29.514 ms  33.038 ms  33.227 ms
 4  sixxs-gw.hotnic.us.occaid.net (2001:4830:e6:7::1)  33.620 ms  33.331 ms  33.742 ms
 5  10gigabitethernet2-2.core1.ash1.he.net (2001:504:0:2::6939:1)  45.001 ms  34.454 ms  45.105 ms
 6  100gigabitethernet7-1.core1.nyc4.he.net (2001:470:0:299::2)  44.345 ms  37.767 ms  38.386 ms
 7  nyc20.tbone.rr.com (2001:504:f::53)  40.832 ms  31.677 ms  42.384 ms
 8  2001:1998::66:109:6:156 (2001:1998::66:109:6:156)  56.682 ms  61.804 ms  62.698 ms
 9  2001:1998:0:8::35 (2001:1998:0:8::35)  62.859 ms  63.053 ms 2001:1998:0:8::ab (2001:1998:0:8::ab)  63.456 ms
10  2604:2000:0:4::2302 (2604:2000:0:4::2302)  58.353 ms  63.118 ms  58.478 ms
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  *^C
```

My best judgment tells me the last router to respond is at least two or three hops away from you, so I would say either TWC hasn't fully implemented it in your area and mistakenly turned on the DHCPv6 server too early, or they implemented it but are having issues. Either way, to get it resolved, you'll have to contact them. Good luck getting past first level support.