# VirtualBox 0x80004005

Tags: virtualbox

I just installed VirtualBox on my pc, this is my config:

```
i7 skylake
8gb ram
hard disk 1tb
ssd 200gb
vga gtx 970
os windows 10
```

I'm trying to perform the installation of windows 7 but when I start the virtual machine I get this error:

[image]

> Opening of a session for the virtual machine win7 failed

Now I've the Hyper-V enable in my pc and also the VT-X and intel virtualization technology is enable in the bios.

This is the log:

http://pastebin.com/y7yKaWRi

Comment: Did you reboot the machine after installing?

Comment: yes, several times

Answer (score 1):

Could be unrelated, but you mentioned you have hyper-v installed. I found virtual box wouldn't work for me unless I disabled hyper-v on boot. I'm not sure if it's the same issue as it happened a while ago, but you could temporarily disable hyper-v to test it using the command from [here](https://superuser.com/a/642027/647472),

To add an option to disable it on boot I used [this method](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx), whose relevant commands are:

```
C:\>bcdedit /copy {current} /d "No Hyper-V" 
The entry was successfully copied to {<some uuid>}. 

C:\>bcdedit /set {<some uuid>} hypervisorlaunchtype off 
The operation completed successfully.
```