# How to disable Hyper-V in Windows forever?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, hyper-v

I am using Oracle VirtualBox oftet, which conflicts with Hyper-V feature of Windows, which I don't use. So, I am turning Hyper-V off.

Nevertheless, from time to time, probably during major upgrades, Windows set it back on again.

How to prohibit this setting forever? May be delete some files or lock subdirectories? Any solution for robot disobey 1st law of robotics appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The question was not how to disable Hyper-V as in "duplicated" ones. The question was how to disable it FOREVER.

For example, this method

[image]

provides only temporary disabling, which will restore on next windows update.

Comment: See this answer:: https://superuser.com/a/642027

Comment: I see that even the original version of your question explicitly said "forever" and "from time to time Windows turns it back on again", and I would not have voted to close. But you would get a lot more sympathy and support if you would actually try *all* the answers to the other question before you ask to have yours reopened.

Comment: @Scot I knew other answeres and disabled Hyper-V. I just don't want to do this again and again.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the "Turn Windows features on and off"

[image]

Comment: This is temporary disabling. It will go back on next windows update.

Comment: Really?  Are you sure?  If so, then that's the only feature that gets automatically enabled upon an update.

Comment: @egray, the OP tends to have some *very* unusual configurations related to his operating system and associated software.  You are absolutely right:  Hyper-V is not "on" by default, even after a big Feature Update.  In all probability, something within the custom configuration on the OP's computer is causing Hyper-V to be repeatedly enabled.  Ultimately, your answer is correct.